# Copying Specific Lines To a .txt File

Tags: list, batch-file

OK, I am using 'ipconfig /displaydns' to display all websites visited (since the last 'ipconfig /flushdns') and I would like to copy **just the website's URL** to Websites.txt.
A typical layout of the output is:

```
ocsp.digicert.com
----------------------------------------
Record Name . . . . . : ocsp.digicert.com
Record Type . . . . . : 5
Time To Live  . . . . : 17913
Data Length . . . . . : 4
Section . . . . . . . : Answer
CNAME Record  . . . . : cs9.wac.edgecastcdn.net


badge.stumbleupon.com
----------------------------------------
Record Name . . . . . : badge.stumbleupon.com
Record Type . . . . . : 1
Time To Live  . . . . : 39560
Data Length . . . . . : 4
Section . . . . . . . : Answer
A (Host) Record . . . : 199.30.80.32


0.gravatar.com
----------------------------------------
Record Name . . . . . : 0.gravatar.com
Record Type . . . . . : 5
Time To Live  . . . . : 2047
Data Length . . . . . : 4
Section . . . . . . . : Answer
CNAME Record  . . . . : cs91.wac.edgecastcdn.net
```

But, I would wish just to have

```
ocsp.digicert.com

badge.stumbleupon.com

0.gravatar.com
```

as the output. Any ideas on how to do that, also I am using a Windows RT device, so external applications are not an option and the output is usually 10 times longer than that, and not all records are the same.

Comment: Are all records the same length? I.e. can you take every 11th line?

Comment: Unfortunately, no they are not all the same length :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PowerShell:

```
ipconfig /displaydns | Select-String 'Record Name' | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "Record Name . . . . . :", ""}
```

Comment: @Ryan Cool!  Please mark my solution answered when you get a chance.